# Is there a way to loop through the return value of np.where?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there a way to loop-through this tuple(?) where the left array are positions in an array and the right array is the value I would like to insert into the given positions:

```
(array([   0,    4,    6, ..., 9992, 9996, 9997]), array([3, 3, 3, ..., 3, 3, 3]))
```

The output above is generated from the following piece of code:

```
np.where(h2 == h2[i,:].max())[1]
```

I would like the result to be like this:

```
array[0] = 3
array[4] = 3
...
array[9997] = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a simple indexing:

```
indices, values = my_tuple

array[indices] = values
```

If you don't have the final array yet you can create it using a desire function like `np.zeros`, `np.ones`, etc. with a size as the size of maximum index.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the `transpose` of the `where` tuple:

```
In [204]: x=np.arange(1,13).reshape(3,4)
In [205]: x
Out[205]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
In [206]: idx=np.where(x)
In [207]: idx
Out[207]: 
(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int32),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int32))
In [208]: ij=np.transpose(idx)
In [209]: ij
Out[209]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 3],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [2, 3]], dtype=int32)
```

In fact there's a function that does just that:

```
np.argwhere(x)
```

Iterating on `ij`, I can print:

```
In [213]: for i,j in ij:
     ...:     print('array[{}]={}'.format(i,j))
     ...:     
array[0]=0
array[0]=1
array[0]=2
```

`zip(*)` is a list version of transpose:

```
for i,j in zip(*idx):
     print(i,j)
```